# Three queens and two rooks covering the chess board... again!

Tags: combinatorics, chess, optimization

Three queens and two rooks can be placed on a chess board so that all empty squares are under attack, as has been shown here: [3 queens and 2 rooks covering a 8x8 chess board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107214/3-queens-and-2-rooks-covering-a-8x8-chess-board).

What if we require that all squares are under attack, even those occupied by any of the five pieces?

[Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048684241X)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I used integer linear programming to minimize the number of unattacked squares.  Here is one optimal solution (unique up to symmetry), with

> 0 unattacked squares:
> \begin{matrix}&.&.&.&Q&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&R&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&R\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\&.&Q&.&.&.&Q&.&.\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\\end{matrix}

Comment: Could you tell us how you came to the solution. Is it unique?

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know it was possible.

Answer (score 7):

I can manage to get

> exactly ***one*** unattacked square:
>
>  [image]
>
>  (namely, the one occupied by the bottom right queen)

Methodology:

> In [hexomino's solution to the previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/107216/5373), I noticed that the problem was essentially reduced to making three queens cover a $6\times6$ chessboard and then using two rooks to cover the remaining two rows and two columns. My only innovation was to shift the position of that $6\times6$ chessboard within the $8\times8$ one.

Comment: Welp, a few minutes after I posted this, Rob Pratt edited his answer from 5 to 0 unattacked squares. +1 to him, but I'll leave this answer in place as it has a nice non-computery method.